# How can I sanitize formatted text for any input in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formatting

I have several inputs on an app using the `Field` component from `redux-forms`, and I'm trying to implement something that allows me to save the input as plain-text and not formatted (i.e., should be saved as Eduardo) when pasted. I guess that I can do something using onPaste, but I have no idea on how to get the plain text from what the user is pasting.

EDIT: There is no actual code but for testing purposes I have this:

```js
<Field
    name="dni"
    component={InputWithFormGroup}
    label={t('
    placeholder={t('
    validate={[required, DNIorNIE]}
    onPaste={(e) => {
        const pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        console.log('Pasted:', pastedText);
        const regex = /(<([^>]+)>|&nbsp;)/ig; 
        const sanitizedString = pastedText.replace(regex, '');
        console.log('Sanitized:', sanitizedString);
    }}
/>
```

And both strings show up as exactly the same, .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm editing the original answer since I see the actual code now. you need to
call *e.preventDefault();* and override the paste functionality as below by using *window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, plainText);*

```
<Field
name="dni"
component={InputWithFormGroup}
label={t('
placeholder={t('
validate={[required, DNIorNIE]}
onPaste={(e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
   window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
}}/>
```

Comment: Doing this still gives me the same problem, since the formatting appears to be RTF instead of HTML. Actually, doing ```event.clipboard.getData('text/html')``` returns the following html:

```<meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><span style=\"font-style: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; widows: auto; word-spacing: ..."></span>```

As you can see, it's still formatted there.

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia What happen if you change it to  event.clipboard.getData('text/plain') ? I think it should give you what you want.

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia I have edited the answer, please mark it as correct if its working for you.

Comment: I still get the text as , even if I try to get it as text/plain

Comment: hmm that's strange. check this out>> https://jsbin.com/noyoquxipa/edit?js,output
maybe try only using event.clipboard.getData('text')

Comment: if it's still not working, could you please update the question with your code so that would be easier to find the exact issue.

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia please check the edited answer, you need to add e.preventDefault(); and override the default paste event

Comment: Still not does what I want it to do. And logging the text variable in the console, also shows up formatted.

Comment: hmm @GonzaloGarcia, yes, you are right. its working fine with everything, but not working for your exact text (). I really have no idea who these formatting persist without any other metadata. even I copy paste this on notepad all styles are there.

Comment: I'm gonna mark your answer as valid since, as you said, it's working with everything else. But for this particular case, I don't know if much else can be done. Thanks anyway though!